# FileFormatException With Inner COMException Thrown By BitmapSource.CopyPixels

Tags: wpf, imaging

I have the following code:

```
BitmapSource bitmap = _bitmapSource;

if (_bitmapSource.Format != PixelFormats.Bgra32)
    bitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap(_bitmapSource, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0);

int bytesPerPixel = (bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
int pixelWidth = bitmap.PixelWidth;
int pixelHeight = bitmap.PixelHeight;
int stride = bytesPerPixel * pixelWidth;
int pixelCount = pixelWidth * pixelHeight;
var pixelBytes = new byte[pixelCount * bytesPerPixel];

bitmap.CopyPixels(pixelBytes, stride, 0);

...

}
```

A NUnit test exercises this code which throws when it reaches `bitmap.CopyPixels`:

```
System.IO.FileFormatException : The image decoder cannot decode the image. The image might be corrupted.
    ----> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F60

at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CriticalCopyPixels(Int32Rect sourceRect, IntPtr buffer, Int32 bufferSize, Int32 stride)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CriticalCopyPixels(Int32Rect sourceRect, Array pixels, Int32 stride, Int32 offset)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CopyPixels(Int32Rect sourceRect, Array pixels, Int32 stride, Int32 offset)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CopyPixels(Array pixels, Int32 stride, Int32 offset)
```

however the image is not corrupted (other tests use the same file without issue) and strangely if I set a breakpoint at `bitmap.CopyPixels` and break in the debugger then continue, the exception is not thrown.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be causing the error for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this, it was quite simple.

`_bitmapSource` was created earlier using a FileStream like so:

```
using(var f = new FileStream(imagePath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read){
    BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(f);
}
CallToCodeInQuestion(bitmap);
```

In the docs for [`BitmapFrame.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe.create.aspx) it says

> The bitmapStream can be closed after the frame is created only when
>   the OnLoad cache option is used. The default OnDemand cache option
>   retains the stream until the frame is needed. Use the Create(Stream,
>   BitmapCreateOptions, BitmapCacheOption) method to specify create and
>   cache options.

So I needed to do this:

```
using(var f = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read){
    BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(
        f,
        BitmapCreateOptions.None,
        BitmapCacheOptions.OnLoad);
}//FileStream has been closed.
CallToCodeInQuestion(bitmap);
```

My NUnit test now passes.